# Exercise 2.26 (Idempotents and products) from Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, localization, idempotents

> **Exercise 2.26 (Idempotents and products):** Show that $R$ can be written as a direct product of two or more (nonzero) rings iff $R$ contains a non-trivial idempotent. Show that if $e$ is an idempotent, then $R = Re\times R(1-e)$ and that $Re$ may be realized as a localization, $Re = R[e^{-1}]$.

I'm most interested in showing that $Re = R[e^{-1}]$. I assume that $R[e^{-1}]$ means localizing at the multiplicative set $U = \{ 1,e \}$ where the fact that $U$ is multiplicative follows from idempotence: $e^2=e$.

*After writing it out, I can't seem to picture what $R[e^{-1}]$ looks like. I show below that $r/1=r/e$ in $R[e^{-1}]$ so does that mean $R[e^{-1}]$ have the same number of elements as $R$? If so, why wouldn't the same proof show that $R\cong Re$? What is special about $R[e^{-1}]$ that makes this work?* Thanks for your help!

I will use the universal property of localization. Let $\varphi:R\to Re$ be the ring homomorphism $r\mapsto re$. (Here, we are treating $Re$ as a ring in its own right with $e\in Re$ being the identity element.) We see that $\varphi(1)=\varphi(e)=e$ and hence $\varphi$ maps $U$ to units.

By the universal property, there is a  map $\psi:R[e^{-1}]\to Re$ given by the following definition (recall that $s=1,e$):
$$ \psi\left(\frac{r}{s}\right) = \varphi(r)\varphi(s)^{-1} = \varphi(r)e = re^2 = re $$
It is clearly surjective. Notice that $r/1=r/e$ because $e(er-r)=er-er=0$. Therefore, to show injectivity it suffices to show that $re=r'e$ (in $Re$) implies $r/1=r'/1$ (in $R[e^{-1}]$). Suppose $re=r'e$ then $(r-r')e=0$. But this exactly means that $r/1=r'/1$. So $\psi$ is a ring isomorphism as desired.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. I'm not sure what you mean by "the same proof" showing that $R \cong Re$, but maybe the following comments will help. The map $\varphi \colon R \to Re$ is not an iso, because it sends $(1-e)$ to $0$. Likewise, the canonical localization map $R \to R[e^{-1}]$ is not an isomorphism for a similar reason: the class of $(1-e)/1$ in $R[e^{-1}]$ is $0$, because $e(1-e) = 0$. In particular, in spite of the relation $r/1 = r/e$ in $R[e^{-1}]$, you're killing off extra stuff in the localization that's nonzero in $R$.

Comment: I see, because $e$ is a zero-divisor, localizing at $e$ kills elements which annhilate it. Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Exercise 2.26 (Idempotents and products): Show that R can be written as a direct product of two or more (nonzero) rings iff R contains a non-trivial idempotent. Show that if e is an idempotent, then R=Re×R(1−e) and that Re may be realized as a localization, Re=R[e−1]."

**Partial-answer:**  Assume $A\cong A_1 \oplus A_2$. It follows $e:=(1,0)\neq 1$ is a non trivial idempotent. Assume conversely that $1\neq e\in A$ is a non trivial idempotent.
Let $I:=(e), J:=(e-1) \subseteq A$ be the ideal generated by $e,e-1$. It follows $I+J=(1)$ hence these ideals are coprime. Moreover $IJ=I\cap J$. Since $IJ:=A(e(e-1))=A(e^2-e)=A(0)=(0)$ is the zero ideal, we get by the CRT an isomorphism

$$ A\cong A/IJ\cong A/I \times A/J$$

where $A/I, A/J \neq 0$. Hence by the CRT we get that $A$ has a non-trivial idempotent iff $A$ may be written as a (non-trivial) direct sum of two rings.