# $A/I$ is a projective $A$-module iff $ I$ is a principal ideal generated by an idempotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

The following question was asked in my assignment of modules and I could not solve this question despite thinking a lot.

> Question: Show that $A/I$ is a projective $A$-module if and only if $I$ is a principal ideal generated by an idempotent element.

Attempt: $\implies$ To show that principal ideal is generated by an idempotent element.

I thought of using the result (I didn’t know which other result can be used): Given $A/I$ is a projective $A$-module. So, we have $F = K \oplus A/I$ such that $F$ is a free $A$-module and $K$ is also an $A$-module.

$\impliedby$  Let $I = (b)$ such that $b^2 = b$. But even here I am not able to prove that $A/I$ is projective (I tried by proving using only the definition).

Can you please shed light?

Comment: In the linked thread the following is proved: A commutative unital ring $A$ may be written as a (non trivial) direct sum $A_1\oplus A_2$ of rings $A_i$ iff $A$ has a non trivial idempotent element $e$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053089/exercise-2-26-idempotents-and-products-from-eisenbuds-commutative-algebra/4070761#4070761 **Question:** Can you please shed light? From this thread and the above argument your result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have the short exact sequence $0 \to I \to A \to A/I \to 0$, and $A$ is a free module. Thus, $A/I$ is projective iff this sequence splits. But this sequence splits iff $I$ is a direct summand of $A$. Can you finish this from here?

Comment: Why is A a free module in 1st line of your answer?

Comment: @IloveJesus: Any ring is a free module over itself (e.g., $\{1\}$ is a basis (if your ring is nonzero)).

Comment: I am not sure I can deduce the result " But this sequence splits iff I is a direct summand of A." Can you please help with this? Also , I will not be able to take it from there. Please help.  Also , thank you very much for replying , even I am looking at my question after a long time!

Comment: Let's go one step at a time. There are two directions to that "iff" condition. For one direction, we can use the fact that a module $P$ is projective iff every sequence of the form $0 \to M \to N \to P \to 0$ splits. Do you see that this gives one direction of the iff statement you were asking about?

Comment: very sorry , but still can't see why I will be principal ie generated by a single element and that too idempotent?

Comment: You're jumping the gun; are you convinced that $A/I$ is projective iff $I$ is a direct summand of $A$?

Comment: Yes I am convinced about this?

Comment: The next step follows from the fact that $I$ is a direct summand of $A$ iff $I$ is generated by an idempotent. $${}$$ ($\implies$): Let $R \to I$ be the splitting. Define $e = f(1)$. Argue that $ex = x$ for all $x \in I$. Thus, $e$ is an idempotent (taking $x = e$) and generates $I$. $${}$$ ($\impliedby$): Conversely, suppose $I = (e)$ for an idempotent $e$. Define the splitting $R \to I$ by $r \mapsto re$ and check that this does the job.